# Using Sum() in Return to calculate OrderByDescending

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

I need some help moving this query to the Neo4jClient please, I am just struggling with the Total.

```
MATCH (p:Product)-[viewed:VIEWED]-()
return p, count(viewed) as count, sum(viewed.total) as total
order by total desc
```

So far I have gotten to this, but I cannot do the Total, or the OrderByDescending.

```
return client.Cypher
            .Match("(product:Product)-[viewed:VIEWED]-()")
            .Return((product,viewed) => new ExploreObject
            {
                Product = product.As<Product>(),
                Count = viewed.Count(),
                Total = ???
            })
            .OrderByDescending(???)
            .Limit(18)
            .Results.ToList();
```

EDIT: After changing the code above to:

```
return client.Cypher
            .Match("(product:Product)-[viewed:VIEWED]-()")
            .Return((product, viewed) => new
            {
                Product = product.As<Product>(),
                Count = viewed.Count(),
                Total = Return.As("sum(viewed.total)")
            })
            .Limit(18)
            .Results.ToList();
```

We still get the error Error: 'The name 'Return' does not exist in the current context'

With total I tried Sum(viewed.total) and Sum("viewed.total") both of which end in error. And with OrderByDescending I cannot order by a number that has not yet been calculated (the Total), so I am stuck, please help.

Shaine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code will return your `ExploreObject` filled with the data you want.
`Return.As` requires you to set a Type parameter (`Return.As<int>` for example) in fact - I'm surprised you got it running at all as it doesn't even compile for me with out the type specified.

It's also important to remember Case. Make sure the properties you are ordering by have the same case as the objects in the query/db. As an example, you return the `sum(viewed.Total)` into a property called `Total`, so when you `ORDER BY` in this case it needs to be `Total` not `total`. Without further ado:

```
return client.Cypher
        .Match("(product:Product)-[viewed:VIEWED]-()")
        .Return((product,viewed) => new ExploreObject
        {
            Product = product.As<Product>(),
            Count = viewed.Count(),
            Total = Return.As<int>("sum(viewed.Total)") //<-- Need to define type here
        })
        .OrderByDescending("Total") //<-- Case sensitive
        .Limit(18)
        .Results.ToList();
```

Another route might be to use `With` again:

```
client.Cypher
    .Match("(product:Product)-[viewed:VIEWED]-()")
    .With("product, viewed, sum(viewed.Total) as summed")
    .Return((product, viewed, summed) => new ExploreObject
    {
        Product = product.As<Product>(),
        Count = viewed.Count(),
        Total = summed.As<int>()
    })
    .OrderByDescending("Total")
    .Limit(18)
    .Results.ToList();
```

Comment: It's my poor programming standard (slightly inherited) that may have caused the confusion, viewed.total is what is on the Graph, Total is just what w2e return as part of the explore object, but this is perfect, thank you.

Comment: Even on the newest version of the code this still fails with: Error 6 The name 'Return' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Are you calling it with `Return.As<T>` or just `Return.As`? (where `T` is `int` in your case)

Comment: .Net 4.6.00057, and according to NuGet I have 1.1.0.9, the dll that it references says 1.1.0.9 in the bin folder. You have pretty much everything, Return.As<int>("sum(viewed.Total)") generates an error in VS, http://ec2-52-89-85-67.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/imagedata/snip.png

Comment: N4JC dll version http://ec2-52-89-85-67.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/imagedata/snip2.png

Comment: Have a look at the edit I've put in place - it does away with the `Return.As` bit, I'm genuinely surprised at this... :/

Comment: Well surprised or not I am now looking at the top 18 most viewed products, sub ordered by the number of unique users who viewed them, so you have the perfect answer. But can we clarify something, do I have a totally different Client to everyone else, or am I just really unlucky? Thanks @Chris Skardon you have freed me up for the weekend, appreciated,

Comment: Honestly - I don't know it's very weird, the `Return.As<T>` has been in the codebase since April 2013. I would (if you could) only use the Nuget packages, if you are shifting to Identity (as I think you mentioned a while ago) at some point - the Neo4j.AspNet.Identity project _does_ use the nuget package, and is up to date.

Comment: I will do it one day, this is a service though, as opposed to a website, all clients pull data from these services and are independent of it, so currently I am using Membership.ValidateUser() for various services and using roles a lot, I haven't seen a good example of using Identity in the same manner, so maybe an architectural change down the line.

Answer (score 2):

Without the ExploreObject

```
return client.Cypher
             .Match("(product:Product)-[viewed:VIEWED]-()")
             .Return((product,viewed) => new
             {
                 Product = product.As<Product>(),
                 Count = viewed.Count(),
                 Total = Return.As("sum(viewed.total)")
             })
             .OrderByDescending(???)
             .Limit(18)
             .Results.ToList();
```

Comment: Sadly not, 'The name Return does not exist in the current context'

Comment: Without the ExploreObject I have no way of returning the items as it needs to be a strongly typed list. Any ideas?

Comment: @ShaineFisher you can cast them to ExploreObject later. e.g. .Select(p => new ExploreObject { ... }).

Comment: In what can be called a quirk, I still get the error about Return does not exist from this, which is really annoying...return client.Cypher
                .Match("(product:Product)-[viewed:VIEWED]-()")
                .Return((product, viewed) => new
                {
                    Product = product.As<Product>(),
                    Count = viewed.Count(),
                    Total = Return.As("sum(viewed.total)")
                })
                .Limit(18)
                .Results.ToList();

Comment: @ShaineFisher Which version of neo4jclient are you using?

Comment: 1.1.0.9 installed using NuGet yesterday.

Comment: Quick question, how do you tell what version you are using if you download the source from git as a zip? Because I have a source version as part of my project too that I am being forced to use as part of the Membership Provider

Comment: The source version doesn't have the assembly info updated, so the only real way is to look for things which are there in the most recent checkins - so for 1.1.0.9 - I'd see if you had the `MemberInfoExtensions` class. Unfortunately it's the only real way - if you have transaction code then you're definitely in 1.1x